# What is the best way to send calls in Angular to an API?

Tags: angular, typescript, api, crud

I have a system made **in Angular** that will perform several many **CRUD operations on an API**. There are **many different calls** in this API: GET, PUT and POST, in other words, many create, update and delete.

Some DELETE, for example, have similar attributes (code), but one has an attribute which other haven't (name, for example).

My questions:

1. What is **the best way to handle the sending of parameters in Angular** to an API (basic approach)?
2. What is the best structure to have?
3. A model for each call, even if it has common attributes?
4. Is possible to have a generic model, and popule only few attributes for each API call?

Answer (score 1):

The HTTPClient that is part of the Angular framework should have what you need. It also has an HttpParams class that you can use to set the params, and create reusable param logic if that is what you need.

This would be the most standard / basic approach as it is built by the Angular team.

https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: Thanks for your response! I need a more generic solution, because I read the docs and the examples only show us passing the full object to API, for example "Hero", not an attribute of object like "Hero.name". 

Do you understand? I need a solution hat I have a object, like a "Person". And I have more than one DELETE calls, for example, and each call have a different request body, but I don't want to make many models.

Comment: I am not sure if I am able to understand you correctly. But you should be able to send any kind of data in the body of your requests, for example you could send a name like this: this.http.post(myUrl, { name: Hero.name }).subscribe();

Answer (score -1):

Try **ngx-restangular** library for calling api from angular